# Url decoding issue in Android

Tags: java, android

I am using this method for URL decoding. It's mostly working properly but some URLs are not working.

Eg:

```
Luke Coughey made comment on Kane Waselenchuk (def) Rocky Carson I I I: Wow%21%20%20This%20I%27d%20going%20too%20be%20another%20season%20of%20dominance%2C%20if%%20Kane%20keeps%20playing%20like%20that%....
```

This string is not decoding I don't know why. Below is my code:

```
public static String getDecodedmessage(String data) {

    try {
        return URLDecoder.decode(data, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Put the url in your code. In the String data. How could we ever test?

Comment: i am assigned the url to that data variable.

Comment: Please try use this  
String decoded_result = Uri.decode(Uri.decode(url));

Comment: its working you are great.......